# How to render content in Ionic tabs without new templates, but by just switching tabs like in bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

We are building a template with three tabs in it. Those tabs are supposed to work like in this example: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-examples

We only want to switch content in the tabs. How can we do that without the need for new templates?

Our detail template is like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{item.summary.name}}">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>


  <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-assertive">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-background-assertive tabs-color-light">
      <ion-tab title="Summary">
        <ion-nav-view name="summary" ></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Ingridents">
        <ion-nav-view name="ingdts"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Videos">
        <ion-nav-view name="video"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </div>

</ion-view>
```

We tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31506520/170445 but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can wrap the `ion-content` of the tab in a `ion-pane` to use static tabs:

```
<ion-tab title="Summary">
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-content>
      <!-- Tab content here -->
      Summary content
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane> 
</ion-tab>
```

Here is a [**codepen example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRKoqR)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller have some type of object to control the visibility:

```
 $scope.pageFlow = {
    summary: true,
    ingts: false,
    video: false
 }
```

Then on you view just show or hide the div's.  You could also create a scope method to handle the control, but not needed.  One thing to note is that the ion-tabs are outside of the ion-content but inside the ion-view

```
<ion-view view-title="{{item.summary.name}}">
 <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>
 <ion-content padding="true" scroll="true" class="has-header">
    <div ng-if="pageFlow.summary">
        Summary Goes Here
    </div>
    <div ng-if="pageFlow.ingdts">
        Ingredients Goes Here
    </div>
    <div ng-if="pageFlow.video">
        Video Goes Here
    </div>
 </ion-content>
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-background-assertive tabs-color-light">>
    <ion-tab title="Summary" on-select="pageFlow.summary = true; pageFlow.video = false; pageFlow.ingdts = false">
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Ingridents" on-select="pageFlow.ingdts = true; pageFlow.video = false; pageFlow.other = false">
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Videos" on-select="pageFlow.video = true; pageFlow.ingdts = false; pageFlow.other = false">
    </ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs></ion-view>
```

I should also note, you will only need one controller for the view now since everything is inside the one content page.

Comment: we just checked it. but nothing is happening on ng-select we made a function on controller and added alert, there is no output and no error in console.

Comment: hmm...  I did change the ion tab section after my initial post.  Can you make sure that you see the updated version.  I copied a wrong code block into the answer

Comment: Did you try the example after I removed the ion-nav-view from your tabs?  The only other thing I can think is you said ng-select in your previous comment when I have on-select.  I would think that should not make a difference, but I have not tested that.

Comment: Yes We might have tried it before you updated it. But We'll go with the @Und3rTow solution as its straight forward. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ionic 5.2.3, and we can use ion-tabs without actual routing by removing "tabs" attribute in ion-tab-button and to get the status which tab is selected, I have used (click) event.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-bottom">
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button (click)="event(1)">
        <ion-icon name="laptop"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label1</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button (click)="event(2)">
        <ion-icon name="cafe"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Label2</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
```

Comment: This doesn't work well as it <ion-tabs> will always render content according to current route, which in case of missing [tab] attribute will be default "/", ie. the root page.